# how to get RSA fingerprint of a remote site in Debian?

Tags: debian, ssh

In Debian you can set up an alioth account. Once you have set up the things, you need to authenticate yourself to Debian. You add your ssh keys via https://wiki.debian.org/Alioth/SSH

All this is fine. Debian also shares its public SSH keys [here](https://db.debian.org/machines.cgi?host=moszumanska)

Now when you try to connect to the site via ssh I get this 256 SHA RSA fingerprint - VbwoMdcyFWByMDQrIOcaUL6c16LV6+80G9+Rs2rtA8E . Now this may be correct, this might not be correct there is no way to say either way because I'm unable to read the remote URL. I did look at: [How to get ssh server fingerprint information](http://www.lysium.de/blog/index.php?/archives/186-How-to-get-ssh-server-fingerprint-information.html) , and hence tried :

```
─[$] ssh-keygen -lf https://db.debian.org/machines.cgi\?host\=moszumanska                                                            [0:44:45]
ssh-keygen: https://db.debian.org/machines.cgi?host=moszumanska: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: I think you may want to try running `ssh-keyscan` first. e.g. `ssh-keyscan <hostname> > keyscan.txt` followed by `ssh-keygen -lf keyscan.txt` will show you the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### SSH host key

The `ssh-keyscan` command is what you need for the host key. It was developed so that users can obtain public host keys without needing to authenticate to the SSH server.  From its man page:

> `ssh-keyscan` is a utility for gathering the public ssh host keys of a
>   number of hosts. It was designed to aid in building and verifying
>   `ssh_known_hosts` files.

For your particular example, the output of `ssh-keyscan moszumanska.debian.org` is

```
# moszumanska.debian.org:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u6
moszumanska.debian.org ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzHN3B7CPXopYu0uswB5NKyro/I88Sgdui4UC80+x6FniylXtRDWSf+psaMAdgqrKHyV/TSWwcgc+Vrh+Us07wBwdOhHUBiPrEh/04KSbijguZHiQeQQWDD0xC+zOJ9Woa6WH+WZARE5aWd3YEupaII7VRG6e3sxUHmMpTMgc19/voPNUqNzrdqKQNKKc1JGKxM4B/7JRmVNHeclNRyXPJKSUSMpe4+g9ldMssKiY8foFFPFA8gQ3oIjIAr/pALm2q4JLpsVoJy/JonkgkjO8iRfklqyTVLrXTaBc0isrVR4pGZ1QFbucJ5LO5rdxPwc1rxcBxK9clhsuUaLz8fv5n
# moszumanska.debian.org:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u6
```

This corresponds with the [published SSH host key](https://db.debian.org/machines.cgi?host=moszumanska).

### SSH host key fingerprint

The `ssh-keygen` command can then be used to get the fingerprint.  I’ve previously written a detailed answer on how [both these commands can be combined](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268692/22812).

```
$ ssh-keygen -lf <(ssh-keyscan moszumanska.debian.org 2>/dev/null)
2048 SHA256:VbwoMdcyFWByMDQrIOcaUL6c16LV6+80G9+Rs2rtA8E moszumanska.debian.org (RSA)
```

Comment: Note that 'published' or otherwise obtained by authenticated means, here https, is vital. Otherwise `ssh-keyscan` can give you a key, and `ssh-keygen` a fingerprint for that key, that is in fact an impostor.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Very true. I think it's great that Debian publish the server keys so users can mitigate MITM attacks.